# Is there any way to ensure my content from raspberry Pi zero is displaying on the TV screen

Tags: raspberry-pi, hdmi, raspberry-pi-zero, edid, hdcp

I have my raspberry Pi zero connected to a tv screen using hdmi for showing some content. How to know when the TV is in off condition and when someone changes the video source. Is there any way to ensure that my content is displaying on the TV.

Is there any command for that.?? I heard about there will be a handshake signal between the the hdmi source and recipient when the data is transferring. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/tvservice.md

You can get the source here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/blob/master/host_applications/linux/apps/tvservice/tvservice.c

You should be able to detect if the TV is connected and turned on with the command line application or roll your own.